# do replacing 'trust with'

Tags: ellipsis, auxiliary-verbs

a. You don't trust your wife with your money but you do your cousin?

b. You don't trust your wife with your money but you do your cousin with it?

c. You don't trust your wife with your money but you trust your cousin?

Are these sentence grammatically correct?

They are supposed to mean:

You don't trust your wife with your money but you trust your cousin with your money?

I think (a) has that meaning, but in (c) the trust seems absolute and (b) sounds strange. I am not particularly fond of (a) either and would never use it, but I think it is grammatical.

Answer (score 2):

All of these examples seem strange to me.

Seems like this is one of those rare occasions where it is necessary to repeat the word "trust", for example:

"You don't trust your wife with your money but you do trust your cousin?"

In your third example, of course, you DO repeat 'trust', but by dropping 'do' it again sounds unnatural to me.